# Internal Members of Friend Assembly Not Accessible in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, access-modifiers

**Problem Statement**

I have two assemblies, one with primarily data contracts and other containing the UI layer.

The data contracts are public and are used in `DataTemplate` tags in the XAML in UI assembly.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type contracts:MyContract}"> 
///other stuff
</DataTemplate>
```

The data contract is assembly is referred like this:

```
<xmlns:contracts="clr-namespace:Contracts.DataContracts,assembly=Contracts.DataContracts"
```

Now I would like to make everything internal DataContract assembly to keep low API surface. I have added UI assembly as friend assembly in the `AssemblyInfo` class of DataContracts assembly. However, I get the following error in the XAML when I compile the UI assembly:

`Only public or internal classes can be used within markup. 'MyContract' type is not public or internal.`

I have checked that the `InternalVisibleTo` is working as I can access other internal stuff in code behind. But in XAML it is not possible.

What are the possible ways to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear on what stuff you are trying to extend from an assembly into your application, but when I have XAML in a library, I tend to reference it this way in an application.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/PathInAssemblyIfNeeded/YourXAMLReferences.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

If this does not help, give more information on what you are a trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not referring the XAML. I am trying to refer types in my XAML which are marked as `internal` in another assembly. But I always get the error as mentioned above. I can definitely access the internal types in my XAML assembly (e.g. in .cs files), but only when I refer them in XAML I get the error. So I want to know if this is specific to WPF?